# Making the image keep looping and showing again with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/NCt4D/8/
Is what I currently got. The loaded image is big:

After it has scrolled to the last iphone screenshot, it stops. I would like it to continue, so it shows from the beginning again.

How would i do this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to set the `scrollTop` to 0? Sounds like you meant to type `scrollLeft`.

Comment: Updated yes thats right fixed

Comment: This doesn't help your issue, but you could look into `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Does the same thing, but doesn't need to be cleared & reset each time.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question, *including* your code. A jsfiddle demo is great, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you're comparing scroll�**Left** with offset�**Height** and scroll�**Height**. Change those to **Width**.

Next, you're returning the scroll position to 0 if the current scroll position is **less than** the maximum. So on the first step the position is 1, which is clearly less than the max, so it jumps back to zero. Result: You're not going anywhere. Try **greater than** instead.

There are a few other things wrong with the code, but they're just optimisations. The two points above are what is majorly wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks. I worked on it, http://jsfiddle.net/NCt4D/10/ , but it still stops at the end

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the `offsetWidth`, and you should use `>=` just to take the equality case into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html) should be a good start.